# C# Convert 2D array to html table

Tags: c#, html, .net, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional string array and i want to convert it to a html table. When i am running the below code it taking a lot of time because of the huge length of array.

```
  string data = string.Empty;
        string table = string.Empty;

        #region new code
        data += "<div class=\"tab-content\">";


        table = " <table class=\"table data-table\">";
        table += "<tbody>";
        for (int row = 1; row < Data.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            table += "<tr>";
            for (int column = 1; column < Data.GetLength(1); column++)
            {
                try
                {
                    table += "<td>" + Data[row, column].ToString() + "</td>";
                }
                catch
                {
                    table += "<td></td>";
                }
            }
            table += "</tr>";
        }
        table += "</tbody>";


        table += "</table>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx). When you do it that way, you are creating multiple string instances because strings are immutable

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar MSDN is the place to search for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4sc8ca8.aspx

Comment: @David the code you gave is not taking any less time than mine. :/

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar are you using a profiler? or just think this is slow and the same as your solution?

Comment: If you want to talk about time use a Profiler, Im sure that if you have a big array of data StringBuilder its faster.

Comment: yes the length of my array is more than 5000 normally and it can exceed up to 20,000

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often that `try { }` blows, I'd try to diagnose whether the indices are legal beforehand. Try-Catch is *really* expensive when it happens a lot.

[Edit:] Wait, it shouldn't be the indices, you are retrieving the bounds. Is this Try-Catch a null-check substitute?

Comment: yes because the array is some times of object type.

Comment: `ToString()` is defined on `object` - that shouldn't blow up. `null`-values would throw an exception, but they are easy to catch, aren't they?

Comment: null object with ToString() will throw up

Comment: that wont save any time. Will do that anyway.